# Convert specific fields before mapping in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to convert two specific fields before mapping to Dto class.
Data i get from form:

```
userName: test
password: 123
active: N
enabled: N
external: N
id: -1
```

Dto class:

```
@Getter @Setter 
public class UserDto {
    protected Integer id;
    protected String userName;
    protected String password;
    protected boolean active = false;
    protected boolean enabled = true;
    protected String external;
}
```

Fields `active` and `enabled` are a boolean type, but from form i get "Y" or "N" string values. Cause of it, i got an error `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'active'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [N]`

I've read about the Сonverter<T,V> and PropertyEditors, but I'm not sure if they work for me and how can i apply it only for 2 specific fields.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@ModelAttribute UserDto userDto, BindingResult bindingResultM, HttpServletRequest req) {

        List<FieldError> errors = bindingResultM.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors) {
            log.error("bindingResultM: " + error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        try {
            userService.saveUserDto(userDto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new ResponseException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are saying you need to **get data from the form** to populate the UserDTO object, which is a process of translate **String type to other type**.

So, you need to use "org.springframework.core.convert.converter.**Converter**", "java.beans.**PropertyEditor**", or "org.springframework.format.**Formatter**". All of three can do the job of translating String type to other type or other type to String type.

But **PropertyEditor** is **too complicated**, so usually we always use Converter or Formatter, and these two can be set in the same method "**default void addFormatters**(FormatterRegistry registry) {}" of the "**WebMvcConfigurer**" interface.

But that's for the whole application, you **only** want the translation happen for "**active**" and "**enabled**" fields of **UserDTO**.

Then you need to use the "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.**InitBinder**", which can be defined **inside the Controller** for **specific method parameter**. The "**userDTO**" of the "**@InitBinder**" means the data binder is only used for the "**userDTO**" **method parameter** inside this Controller. (This name is **case-sensitive**, so if you "userDto" in the method, you need to change it to userDto in the @InitBinder annotation.)
Inside this method, you can **specify the Formatter** only for "**active**" and "**enabled**" fields, by using this method:

```
public void addCustomFormatter(Formatter<?> formatter, String... fields){}
```

Of course you can specify the **Converter** for these two fields, but there is **no direct method** for it in the "WebDataBinder" class. So, it is **eaiser** to use the **Formatter**.

```
@InitBinder("userDTO")
public void forUserDto(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new BooleanFormatter(), "active", "enabled");
}
```

Here is the BooleanFormatter class:

```
public class BooleanFormatter implements Formatter<Boolean>{

    @Override
    public String print(Boolean object, Locale locale) {
        if (object) {
            return "Y";
        }
        return "N";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        if (text.equals("Y")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your DTO you can annotate your boolean fields with :

```
    @JsonDeserialize(
        using = BooleanDeserializer.class
    )
    protected boolean enabled;
```

And create the deserializer :

```
public class BooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String booleanValue = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(jsonParser.getText().trim());
        return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(booleanValue, "Y", "N");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still getting an error. Seems like deserializer somehow is not getting called